# Plugin in intellij that run in intellij start up

Tags: intellij-plugin

I want to write a plugin in intellij. Can I create an plugin for intellij that runs in the background as soon as the user opens the intellij IDE?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the `ProjectComponent` interface (which is run on project loading). This class needs to be registered as `project-components` in your plugin.xml. There are also other components like `ApplicationComponent`.

For more information see: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+Plugin+Structure#IntelliJIDEAPluginStructure-PluginComponents